# Receiving error when I add the scala nature to project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

How can I use scala and java within Eclipse ? When I add the scala nature to my project I receive below error :

> Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Scala
>   Builder' on project 'my-scala-java-project'.
>   scala/tools/nsc/settings/MutableSettings$SettingValue

I'm using Eclipse Helios with Scala version 2.0.2

Is there a step I am missing or maybe this is a Eclipse/Scala plugin bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scala IDE is under rapid development, I'd suggest updating to the latest version first, and if it doesn't solve the issue, contact the developers at the [scala-ide-user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/scala-ide-user).

Btw [this thread might](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-ide-user/TSQ0F4r86QU/tQtCMzwdAAEJ) help you get started.